# Domain of definition.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

What is the difference between domain of a function $f$ and its domain of definition? I searched it in my books but did't got the answer. I am thinking like this

If $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function (say) $f(x)=x^{2}$ then domain of $f$ is $ [0,1]$ and its domain of definition is $\mathbb{R}$.

Please give me the right definition. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No difference; see [Domain of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) : "In mathematics the *domain of definition* (or simply the *domain*) of a function is the set of "input" or argument values for which the function is defined."

Comment: but some times we say domain and some times as domain of definition...

Comment: sometimes (for example in convex analysis) we consider functions mapping something into $\mathbb{R}\cup\left\{\infty\right\}$. The Domain is then the set of points where the function is defined and finite.

Answer (score -1):

domain of f is referring to the specified given cases.For example in real life, we always have bound for different function.(populationzxac cost, profit)

domain of definition only lies on the definition. It is a general case ignoring the bound.